# How to divide the th element in table?

Tags: html

I have the following `th` in table:

```
<th colspan="2">Результат</th>
```

I want to devide this element like in attached picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
<th>Результат</th><th></th>
```

That will place the first text with the first column and the second one empty

Comment: Just add new th after?

Comment: Yes, if you only want another empty cell that'll do it.

Comment: And remove the `colspan="2"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the inclined divider inside `th`. Check the sample.

```css
table {
  width: 150px;
}

th {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.separator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: solid 1px #f00;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -ms--transform: rotate(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="col">Hello</div>
          <i class="separator"></i>
          <div class="col">World</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```